# Scaling text to fit inside its container

Tags: css, vue.js

So I use v-for to map out some objects out of an array. Those cards contain some text, that I put inside a card. Those cards form a whole section, and should all be the same height. I could use max-height and scale text with @media and screen width, but that means I would have 5-6 @media rules for the text, manually scaling it so the container keeps the same height.

I've tried using different rules for font-size, such as clamp, calc, vw and line-clamp (which did put '...' at the end of the second line, but the text then would go further without being cut there). To put it in the card I used {{title.substring(0, 50)}}.

I was told that there is a nice, simple and clean way to scale text so it fits the container without changing its dimensions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use SVG to scale the text:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 80 20">
    <text x="2" y="15">Hello world</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```